# MySQL Backup Database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I found a query from [HERE](http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/database/mysql/backup.html) on how to backup the database but it is not working and it throws an error. Any help please. TIA

**CODE:**

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
public bool BackupDatabase(string filename = "")
{
    bool _isExecuted = false;

    if (filename == "")
    {
        filename = string.Format("{0}/db_{1:MMddyyyyHHmmss}.sql", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), DateTime.Now);
    }

    string _queryBackup = string.Format("mysqldump -u '{0}' -p '{1}' '{2}' > '{3}'", DatabaseUsername, DatabasePassword, DatabaseName, filename);         
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(_queryBackup, con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _isExecuted = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string _x = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    return _isExecuted;
}
```

**ERROR:**

**_x** contains this error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'mysqldump -u 'root' -p 'usbw' 'my_database_name' >
>   'C:\Users\DesktopName\Desktop\db_08242012164022.sql' at line 1"

Comment: You can consider MySqlBackup.NET as alternative to MySqlDump. Read more: https://github.com/MySqlBackupNET/MySqlBackup.Net

Answer (score 1):

Your _queryBackup is not an sql query string but a string to run from the system, as if you run it from the cmd console.

Here is some code to run a command such as yours from C#

```
  var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command, parameterstring);
  startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
  Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
  StreamReader stdoutSR = process.StandardOutput;
  string stdout = stdoutSR.ReadToEnd();
  StreamReader stderrSR = process.StandardError;
  string stderr = stderrSR.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: ahhh.. so, is there any sql query string to backup the database? so the given method is applicable?