# backup mysql database and convert it to sqlite to use it in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, mysql

my project manager asked me to do the following:

-backup data from mysql database that is on the server

-convert this data to sqlite

-add it to a windows form application that read from this sqlite new database

the target is to keep part of the database always linked to this c# windows application

I've read articles about backup data from mysql using c# and I don't expect to have problems

[backup using mysqldump.exe 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686256/how-to-backup-the-database-using-mysql-and-c-net)

[backup using mysqldump.exe 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105898/mysql-backup-database-in-c-sharp)

[backup using mysqldump.exe 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738361/mysql-database-backup-using-c-sharp)

How can I convert this mysql dump file into sqlite and load the data to the c# using the sqlite memory and then save it so the application will use this sqlite database each time it runs. All of these steps must be done by the c# windows application itself with a button or something similar.

Comment: I would do a `Google`Search on how to convert MySQL over to Sqlite there are a lot of steps you have there so my best suggestion would be to start coding as well as start doing some research on the web

Comment: why can't you use a conversion tool.. sounds like the company you work for is being `cheap` [sql conversion tools](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools) start looking here Tony

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?145,68269,92627#msg-92627

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO easiest way to do this, and how we do it: export the tables as CSV.  Open them in excel.  create an insert statement for the first row in the excel sheet using variables for the cells, append that as an extra column.  click and drag that down to repeat that statement on every row.

Copy that generated column, and bring it into your sqlite database browser, and run that huge statement.

the statement should look like : `="INSERT INTO newTable VALUES('" &A2&"','" &B2&"');"`

don't make it any harder then it should be :P